# Why are the hottest stars appear mostly in blue or blue-white?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, temperature, thermal-radiation, stars

Does it have to do with anything regarding wavelengths and frequencies..

Comment: It isn't an exact duplicate, but the question [How is temperature related to color?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116302/) basically covers this. In fact the question uses different temperature stars as an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is temperature related to color?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116302/)

Comment: @JohnRennie yeah after reading the thread you shared i got a basic understanding about this. But didnt quite understand it in a systematic way. Thanks for the help

Comment: @AlphaLife It does but still not the exact answer i wanted. Thanks for the help